# Custom templates with phpDocumentor 2

Tags: phpdoc

I've been trying to get a custom template to work with PHPDocumentor (2) without much luck. The documentation on their site is incomplete and I'm kind of stumped.

What I've done is downloaded a copy of a complete template and reference it in my command, like so:

```
php phpdoc.php 
    --template=/path/to/customtemplate/ 
    -d /path/to/php/source/files 
    -t /path/to/generated/content/
```

The command runs fine: it generates the documentation correctly but appears to be ignoring the `--template` option - at least, any changes I make to the template files in the `/customtemplate` folder are ignored.

Anyone have any idea?

(Thanks in advance!)

- Ben

Comment: phpDocumentor is totally weird. No matter what I do it generates from the default template. Even if I change the files in the original template and search through every single file in the entire phpdoc folder, it generates text and comments that I find NOWHERE in any source files! It even says it is using my template when I run phpdoc - but nope! How is that possible?! It's like it is using a secret cache somewhere. Besides, documentation is pathetic - nearly empty pages, broken links etc - doesn't explain anything properly...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring the template command on the CLI you might try changing your phpdoc.dist.xml configuration file so that it pulls the template name or path from there directly.